# What is the correct usage of [sqlbindparameter]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tag [sqlbindparameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlbindparameter) has 121 questions out of which only 9 of them are tagged with [odbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odbc) and are really about [ODBC's `SQLBindParameter` function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindparameter-function?view=sql-server-2017). The rest is about generic parameter binding in prepared statements.

Part of the problem is that there is no tag guidance. People seem to think that this applies to parameter binding in all other languages/frameworks e.g. pdo, mysqli.

What could we do about this tag? Add tag-wiki and re-tag, burninate or leave it as it is?

Some edge cases:
[Can I bookmark SQL query with bind parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51102910/1839439)
[The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to push the transaction using AmbientTransaction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39974278/1839439)
[What's the equivalent of eclipselink.jdbc.bind-parameters for OpenJPA (Kodo)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17915707/1839439)
[PHP Passing an Array As A Function's Parameters Using (...$array)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39880335/1839439)
[How to properly pass and return by reference between function inside a class (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29059808/1839439)
[InputStream doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20328378/1839439)

Answer (score 1):

After some more research I think it will be a good idea to re-tag most of these questions and leave only the ones which are about ODBC's SQLBindParameter function. If someone could suggest a tag wiki, it would be great.

All the PHP questions, both with PDO and MySQLi prepared statements can be re-tagged to [bindparam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bindparam):

> In PHP, binds a variable to a corresponding named or question mark parameter in the SQL statement that was used to prepare the statement.

I know this is for PDO's `bindParam()` method, but I see no reason to create a separate one for mysqli.

If there are no objections, I am willing to do this, but I am also open to other proposals.

Some other possible tags: [sqlparameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameters), [sqlparameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameter) (both for C# sqlParameter function)